# Replacing the duplicate values except 1 row in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I replace the duplicated values of a specific column of R dataframe to NA (except the first row) based on ID. To give an example:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c("p1","p1","p1","p2","p2"),date=c("d1","d1","d1","d2","d2"))
```

and should result in the following:

```
x2 <- data.frame(id=c("p1","p1","p1","p2","p2"),date=c("d1","NA","NA","d2","NA"))
```

I have to maintain the data structure of multiple rows per id, simply do not want the date values to be repeated but once.

Thanks

Comment: `x$date[duplicated(x$date)] <- NA` ?

Comment: Thanks, it has to be duplicate dates for each Id. Basically, I am grouping by ID and want to replace the duplicated dates except 1.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x$id), function(g) { g$date[duplicated(g$date)] <- NA; g }))` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** A base R method is to use `ave()` replace the duplicated `date` values with `NA` for each group in `id`.

```
x$date <- ave(
    x$date, 
    x$id, 
    FUN = function(a) replace(a, duplicated(a), NA_integer_)
)
```

which gives the updated `x` data

> ```
>   id date
> 1 p1   d1
> 2 p1 <NA>
> 3 p1 <NA>
> 4 p2   d2
> 5 p2 <NA>
> ```

The method above will work for multiple values in `date`, replacing duplicates with `NA`.  If it's only the first group value you're after, you could use the code above or the following, which may be faster.

```
ave(
    x$date,
    x$id,
    FUN = function(a) c(a[1], a[-1][NA])
)
```

This code takes the first value in each group and replaces all the rest with `NA`. It's not clear which one you want, since your example data only has one value per `id` group.

**Option 2:** An alternative using the *data.table* package. Since `NA` is logical, `date[NA]` simply turns values into `NA` without changing the type of the data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[duplicated(date), date := date[NA], by = id]
```

which gives

> ```
>    id date
> 1: p1   d1
> 2: p1   NA
> 3: p1   NA
> 4: p2   d2
> 5: p2   NA
> ```

Comment: Thanks for multiple ways of solution !

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
x3<-data.table(x)

x3[, `:=` (date = ifelse(duplicated(date), NA, date)), by = id]
x3

id date
p1   d1
p1   NA
p1   NA
p2   d2
p2   NA
```

In general, it is advised to use `:=` with caution because the adjustments you tell it to make are permanent. However, in this case that is what we are after and it saves using `<-` to define/redefine columns as needed. See `?data.table` for more information.

Comment: Thank you Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

**BENCHMARK**

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
dff <- data.frame(id=c("p1","p1","p1","p2","p2"),date=c("d1","d1","d1","d2","d2"))

func_Bryan.Goggin <- function(x){x3<-data.table(x);x3[, `:=` (date = ifelse(duplicated(date), NA, date)), by = id];}
func_Richard.Scriven <- function(x){x$date <- ave(x$date, x$id, FUN = function(a) replace(a, duplicated(a), NA_integer_));}
func_r2evans <- function(x){groupedx <- by(x, x$date, function(df) {within(df, date <- c(as.character(date[1]), rep(NA, nrow(df) - 1)))});Reduce(rbind, groupedx);}
microbenchmark(func_Bryan.Goggin(dff), func_Richard.Scriven(dff), func_r2evans(dff))

Unit: microseconds
                      expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    func_Bryan.Goggin(dff) 791.436 816.827 886.0153 848.9770 880.9765 1733.408   100
 func_Richard.Scriven(dff) 130.103 146.630 157.8821 154.1410 164.3570  305.277   100
         func_r2evans(dff) 590.423 615.662 668.7100 637.8975 656.5260 1607.511   100
```

**EDIT**

I excluded `func_Richard.Scriven2` from the benchmark since it will call by reference.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c("p1","p1","p1","p2","p2"),
                date=c("d1","d1","d1","d2","d2"))
groupedx <- by(x, x$date, function(df) {
                 within(df, date <- c(as.character(date[1]), rep(NA, nrow(df) - 1)))
               })
Reduce(rbind, groupedx)
#   id date
# 1 p1   d1
# 2 p1 <NA>
# 3 p1 <NA>
# 4 p2   d2
# 5 p2 <NA>
```

(I used `as.character` because of your use of factors in the `data.frame`, and without it the strings are converted into their factor integers. If you use actual strings, you should be able to omit it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help.