# Weird Printing Behavior after microbenchmark in R

Tags: r, scoping, microbenchmark

I was following up on @m0h3n's post on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766541/replacing-the-duplicate-values-except-1-row-in-r-dataframe/37766774#37766774) question asked a few days ago and I noticed that R was acting strange after running `microbenchmark()`. Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

data<- data.table(id=c("p1","p1","p1","p2","p2"),date=c("d1","d1","d1","d2","d2"))
p<-5 #just to test after benchmark

func_Bryan.Goggin <- function(x){x[, `:=` (date = ifelse(duplicated(date), NA, date)), by = id];x}
func_Richard.Scriven1 <- function(x){x$date <- ave(x$date, x$id, FUN = function(a) replace(a, duplicated(a), NA_integer_));x;}
func_Richard.Scriven2 <- function(x){x[duplicated(date), date := date[NA], by = id];x;}
func_r2evans <- function(x){groupedx <- by(x, x$date, function(df) {within(df, date <- c(as.character(date[1]), rep(NA, nrow(df) - 1)))});Reduce(rbind, groupedx);groupedx;}
microbenchmark(func_Bryan.Goggin(data), func_Richard.Scriven1(data), func_Richard.Scriven2(data), func_r2evans(data))
#note I changed these functions from the original post a little to see how speed was affected.

p # [1] 5

data # nothing, wont print
data # works
```

After running the benchmark, calling to `data` returns nothing. I added the `p<-5` to see if it knew what that was, and it worked fine, but asking for `data` after running the benchmark returns nothing. It will print regularly upon asking for it a second time.

This isn't really a huge issue, but I was wondering if anyone knew what was causing this to happen. Directly after running `microbenchmark()` I tried `print(data)` and `return(data)` (in case it was wrapped up in one of the functions) and it still would not print the first time. I am guessing it is some sort of scoping issue, but I am not an expert in that area. I also checked `environment()` which returns `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`.

Comment: I think the [README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/README.html) of the data.table package explains this behavior. See item number 1 in the "bug fixes" section of "Changes in v1.9.6".

Comment: Yeah, that actually fixes it. Putting `[]` at the end of the functions that use `:=` lets it print, as does calling `data[]` directly after running the test. Thanks.